# How do I configure Apache using pip install mod_wsgi? (Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias')

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

In the process of getting my Django app running in production, I became aware that apt-get mod_wsgi didn't install the correct version of mod_wsgi. And the advice was to pip install mod_wsgi in my virtual environment.

I'm running an AWS Small Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS server and Python 3.5.

My virtual environment is /usr/local/pulseenv and contains mod-wsgi 4.6.4.

My vhost file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf) has:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/pulsemanager/pulsemanager


        Alias /static /var/www/pulsemanager/pulsemanager/static
        <Directory /var/www/pulsemanager/pulsemanager/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/pulsemanager/config>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/pulsemanager/config/wsgi.py 
        #WSGIDaemonProcess pulsemanager 
        WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/pulseenv
        WSGIPythonPath /var/www/pulsemanager
        #WSGIProcessGroup pulsemanager
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to start apache, I get this error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-84-213:~$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-05-04 01:35:16 UTC; 13s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6697 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 04 01:35:16 ip-172-31-84-213 apache2[6697]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
May 04 01:35:16 ip-172-31-84-213 apache2[6697]: Output of config test was:
May 04 01:35:16 ip-172-31-84-213 apache2[6697]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 42 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
May 04 01:35:16 ip-172-31-84-213 apache2[6697]: Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included
May 04 01:35:16 ip-172-31-84-213 apache2[6697]: Action 'configtest' failed.
May 04 01:35:16 ip-172-31-84-213 apache2[6697]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 04 01:35:16 ip-172-31-84-213 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 04 01:35:16 ip-172-31-84-213 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
May 04 01:35:16 ip-172-31-84-213 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 04 01:35:16 ip-172-31-84-213 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

So it seems like mod_wsgi must not be found by Apache. (Is that where the WSGI* commands are?) So how do I configure Apache using pip install mod_wsgi?

Comment: Did you run ``mod_wsgi-express module-config`` and add the result into your Apache configuration? Details in section 'Connecting into Apache installation' of https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/

Comment: BTW, you really should use daemon mode as it is the recommended deployment method. Details on how to configure the virtual environment for that can be found in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. That problem's solved! If you put this in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way of setting up mod_wsgi is to run each WSGI application in its own daemon process group.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp

WSGIProcessGroup myapp
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/pulsemanager/config/wsgi.py 

<Directory /var/www/pulsemanager/config>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

refer:https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guides/virtual-environments.html